# Best approach for multi-page WPF application

Tags: wpf, navigation

How do I create multislide application in WPF? What is best approach? What I need is something very similar to having tabcontrol with multiple pages and navigation buttons below, but I don't think that tab control is best for this task. I would like to have each view to be in separate .xaml + class file. AND- it would be cool to have some animation, when navigating to another page (like old page slides away or something like that.
What would be best technique to achieve this?

---

#### SOLUTION

Solution in deed was to use MVVM + i sliding animation i performed by catching moment, when content get changed for "active view" content control using this technique -
[WPF - data binding trigger before content changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599788/wpf-data-binding-trigger-before-content-changed)

afet that I store current content in image using RenderTargetBitmap and use simple animation to slide Image away and active content in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had success using a wizard style with "Next" and "Back" buttons.  The design involved a WPF View and a controlling ViewModel similar to a Masterpage in ASP.NET. The commands attached to the next/back buttons determined which view/viewmodels to load up into the page region.  The master viewmodel was also responsible for triggering a sliding animation during a page transition.

Using an IOC container to load up view/viewmodels in a decoupled fashion worked well, and [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Wikipage) seemed to to an adequate job managing the various page regions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) in the WPF documentation?  What don't you like about the tools and techniques described there?